# How to compare array with find() in mongoDB meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

*For an array Templates, I want to compare its elements with the MongoDb entries.*

**Templates=[A,B,C]**

```
for(Templates) {
            Template.displayProduct.PendingProducts = products.find({"TEMPLATE_NAME": <Compare here, this is the doubt>}, {
                "Price": 1,
                "Brand": 1,
                "ProductId": 1,
                _id: 0
            });
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values)?

Comment: yes something from this sort, Array Templates is also taken from mongoDB

Comment: If you mean match instead of compare then use the $elemMatch operator

Comment: I don't know, it seems given your `for` statement that you just want to iterate over templates and get their products...

Comment: Ya I want to match only

Comment: I want the array elements to be matched with the template names in product db

Comment: Please also suggest the reason for down vote,answer not available anywhere.plz guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a `name` field on your templates, you can use `forEach` and put in your template's name directly

```
Templates.forEach(function (temp) {
            Template.displayProduct.PendingProducts = products.find({"TEMPLATE_NAME": temp.name}, {
                "Price": 1,
                "Brand": 1,
                "ProductId": 1,
                _id: 0
            });
    });
```

But even with this code, you just end up with the results from the latest loop cycle in `Template.displayProduct.PendingProducts`.

Comment: As I said, this is assuming your templates have a `name` property. You created that collection right?

Comment: Then shouldn't it be .find({'Templates.0': temp.name})

Comment: Template is an array generated from mongoDb query only

Comment: I would gladly help you, but I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve... what is `Template.displayProduct.PendingProducts`?